# get postgres to use an index when querying timestamps in a function

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing

I have a system with a large number of tables that contain historical data. Each table has a `ts_from` and `ts_to` column which are of type `timestamptz`. These represent the time period in which the data for a particular row was valid.

These columns are indexed.

If I want to query all rows that were valid at a particular timestamp, it is trivial to write the `ts_from <= @at_timestamp AND ts_to >= @at_timestamp` `WHERE` clause to utilitise the index.

However, I wanted to create a function called `Temporal.at` which would take the `@at_timestamp` column and the `ts_from` / `ts_to` columns and do this by hiding the complexity of the comparison from the query that uses it. You might think this is trivial, but I would also like to extend the concept to create a function called `Temporal.between` which would take a `@from_timestamp` and `@to_timestamp` and select all rows that were valid between those two periods. That function would not be trivial, as one would have to check where rows partially overlap the period rather than always being fully enclosed by it.

The issue is this: I have written these functions but they do not cause the index to be used. The query performance is woefully slow on the history tables, some of which have hundreds of millions of rows.

The questions therefore are:
a) Is there a way to write these functions so that we can be sure the indexes will be used?

b) Am I going about this completely the wrong way and is there a better way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated if you model `ts_from` and `ts_to` as two different timestamp columns. Instead, you should use a range type: `tstzrange`. Then everything will become simple:

- for containment in an interval, use `@at_timestamp <@ from_to`
- for interval overlap, use `tstzinterval(@from_timestamp, @to_timestamp) && from_to`

Both queries can be supported by a GiST index on the range column.

Comment: I had a feeling I was missing something fundamental. Thank you!